# Using apache camel xml route, how can I set a customized fileName from a JMS message?

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, apache-camel

With the java JMS API, I got from a DB an array of bytes and then I'm sending it to an ActiveMQ as  a javax.jms.BytesMessage.  After that with camel I want to put the file on a location,

I have this route in camel:

```
    <route>
        <from uri="activemq:queue.fileOuput"/>
        <convertBodyTo type="java.nio.ByteBuffer"/>
        <to uri="file://C:/output/"/>
    </route>
```

But my problem is that my file in `c:\output\` directory, I got the file with the message id as the file name, like 
 `queue-preVerificacion-fileoutput-ID-jmachine-57401-1347652410053-0-1-1-1-1`
but I want to put the name I have in the database, like `MyFile.xml`.

I have tried to set a message property like fileName and file:name, and also I saw in the apache document that I need to put a header "org.apache.camel.file.name", but with jms I don't know how to do it.

So my question is how can I put a customized name in the camel route?

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just place the file name in the jms message (as a string property).

```
// Something like this if you send the message using plain java/jms:
msg.setStringProperty("filename","MyFile.xml");
..//Send msg
```

Then you can do something like this in camel

```
<to uri="file://C:/output/?fileName=${header.filename}"/>
```

Comment: This will not work as the to uri is evaluated at build time of the route. The solution above with the CamelFileName header should work.

Comment: @ChristianSchneider: It works like a charm. the filename supports the "file expression language"= simple language to do interpretation at runtime, not route build time. Just tested this route: 

`<route>
   <from uri="activemq:queue:foo.in"/>
   <to uri="file://C:/output/?fileName=${header.filename}"/>

  </route>`

With two different messages (where the string property filename=MyFile.txt and filename=YourFile.txt), they are created just as expected in c:\output\MyFile.txt and c:\output\YourFile.txt)

Answer (score 3):

you just need to set the "CamelFileName" header value (based on a message header, etc)

```
<route>
    <from uri="activemq:queue.fileOuput"/>
    <convertBodyTo type="java.nio.ByteBuffer"/>
    <setHeader headerName="CamelFileName">
        <constant>${header.fileName}</constant>
    </setHeader>
    <to uri="file://C:/output/"/>
</route>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think "org.apache.camel.file.name" is for camel 1.x , in the 2.x version CamelFileName worked fine. But I wanted a more dynamic file name, name based on the content. This example using a processor worked well ( camel 2.18 )

```
 <route>
    <from uri="MQ:MY_Q_NAME" />
    <process ref="MyMessageProcessor"/>
    <to uri="file://E:\OUTPUT" />
</route>

    Inside the Processor :     

exchange.getIn().setHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME, myFileName);
```